# How to extract ONLY the contents of the JDK installer

Tags: installation, extract, java

I just downloaded the Java SDK/JDK versions 5 and 6, and I just need the development tools (and some libraries) contained in the installation packages, I don't need to perform an installation and that's why I was only looking for a zip package at first (for Windows there is only an exe installation file), I only need to extract the contents of the installation packages, I think this can be done from the command line but so far I haven't found how to do this (I already considered WinRar and 7-Zip, but I really want to find how to do it without using these tools)

Have you done this before and how?

Comment: I suspect this may be against the T's and C's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the installation once and then zip up the installed stuff placed under \Programs\Java.

This can be unzipped elsewhere later and used as a JDK in most IDE's without needing a full reinstall (but then Windows does not know about it)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have decided to do =)

Comment: This is how I do it.   I have my own JDK zip/install  that requires no installation and includes 3rd party libraries I need, such as JCE .

Answer (score 8):

Here's .bat script for unpacking "pack" files. Must be run in the root of unzipped JDK.

```
@echo off
echo **********************
echo unpack JDK pack-files
echo **********************
pause

set JAVA_HOME=c:\glassfish4\jdk7

setlocal enableextensions
for /r %%f in (*) do call :process %%f
endlocal
goto :eof

:process
if NOT "%~x1" == ".pack" goto :eof
set FOLDER=%~p1

set PWD=%CD%
pushd %FOLDER%
echo Unpacking %~nx1
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\unpack200.exe %~nx1 %~n1.jar
popd

goto :eof
```

Comment: Great thank you!

However, I changed it to use unpack200.exe from the JDK archive and also to remove the pack file after conversion:

EDIT: moved as answer to get proper indentation.

Answer (score 7):

I use 7-zip to do that. It seems to handle that installer/self-extracting executables nicely.

Comment: @Abel: You just open the installer with 7-Zip - I've done this before.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this one, and worked great for JDK 6, but for JDK 5 I get files that are useless and that I'm sure that need to be handled in some way by the installer in order to be converted to something useful.

Answer (score 4):

I've created cygwin script to do that:
https://gist.github.com/4ndrew/f9dca61cedf0e8340b54

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage example: prepareJdk.sh jdk-7u67-windows-x64.exe (result will be in jdk/)
# Requires: p7zip, unzip

JDK_EXE=$1
7z x -ojdk "$JDK_EXE"
unzip jdk/tools.zip -d jdk/

find jdk/ -type f \( -name "*.exe" -o -name "*.dll" \) -exec chmod u+rwx {} \;

rm jdk/tools.zip
find jdk/ -type f -name "*.pack" | while read eachFile; do
   echo "Unpacking $eachFile ...";
  ./jdk/bin/unpack200.exe $eachFile ${eachFile%.pack}.jar;
  rm $eachFile;
done
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. The problem is, there are just some useless compressed data files in there not the src.zip (1.8.1u131) I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

You can extract both JDK 1.5 and 1.6 from .exe files, using the Universal Extractor (really a great tool). But don't forget to convert all *.pack files (compressed with [Pack200](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack200) format) into corresponding *.jar files, in order to obtain a full working environment. You can use the unpack200.exe command provided in the JDK itself.

Comment: this was the step I was missing. if you don't unpack rt.pack (runtime) then you can't really use the new jvm at all because the classloader can't find the Object class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract). The site looks legit, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is [e-egiazarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2945891/e-egiazarov)'s script, modified to use `unpack200.exe` from the JDK archive and also to remove the pack file after conversion.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions
for /r %%f in (*) do call :process %%f
endlocal
goto :eof

:process
if NOT "%~x1" == ".pack" goto :eof
set FOLDER=%~p1

set PWD=%CD%
pushd %FOLDER%
echo Unpacking %~nx1
%PWD%\bin\unpack200.exe %~nx1 %~n1.jar
del %~nx1
popd

goto :eof
```

Comment: What was the last JDK you extraced/installed that way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. However since that broke I'm now using 7z to extract the JDK installer first and then tools.zip. Then I invoke unpack and I rename the files.

Comment: In the meantime I found an instruction that had been updated recently: https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/portable-java-8-sdk-on-windows/#comment-4854; it describes where to find tools.zip these days.

Answer (score 0):

a little late to the party

here's an extractor written in powershell

```bsh
param($installdir)

$list=$(gci -Recurse ./$installdir/*.pack) | %{
    return @{
        source=$_.FullName
        parent=$_.Directory.FullName
        target="$($_.Directory.FullName)\$([io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)).jar"
    }
} | %{
    $result = $(unpack200 $_.source $_.target)
    $_result=$result
    return $_
}

Write-Host $(ConvertTo-Json $list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Being in the folder where it was unzipped by 7zip, the same one that has the bin and lib folders, the command below does the "magic" in Windows, of course. Thanks.

`for /f %f in ('dir /s/b *.pack') do bin\unpack200.exe %~pf%~nxf %~pf%~nf.jar`