# java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, classpath

Am facing problem with java setting.
My `JAVA_HOME` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09`
`PATH` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin` .
When I try run the command `java -version`, it is throwing an error :

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Comment: It means your JDK is incomplete. I suspect the JRE is missing or not accessible. Check you have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\lib\rt.jar`

Comment: Some problem with installation of the JDK and JRE. You might need to reinstall. May be install under c:\jdk1.7.0 to remove the problem of spaces in folders in windows(ie.Program Files)

Comment: Try replacing "Program Files" in the environemnt variables with "PROGRA~1".

Comment: I had also face same problem, just uninstall current setup of Java & then re-install.

Comment: I see this is closed, but I just had a similar problem and got help from this answer, which should tell us that is might not be too localized.

Comment: Encountered such error when starting JRE from files manually unpacked from installer (without actual JRE installation). `unpack200 rt.pack rt.jar` resolved the issue.

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11808829/640030, which has a list of possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

I think your JDK/JRE installation has a problem. Also once you've installed it correctly, you need to make sure that you add it to the `PATH`.