# Bash_profile file editing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, centos

I am using CentOS. I installed Java8 from the rpm.

Following the tutorial I did this:

> export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
>
> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

However, when I disconnect from SSH it has gone. How can I save the above into the .bash_profile? I believe this is the best way to resolve this problem.

Following this tutorial:

> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23710887/3776858

Comment: Saving them into the `.bashrc` (better) or `.profile` in your home directory will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an environment variable permanently, you can write the `export` command line to /etc/profile.d/ (for system wide change) or ~/.bash_profile (for local user).

NOTE: bashrc will be executed whenever a new terminal is opened (AFTER there is a logged in user).

bash_profile will be executed whenever a user is logging in (no matter is it's via ssh or actually sitting in front of the computer)

You can always export the envvars in one file and by sourcing this file in the other file you will have those envvars in both login/non-login shells:

```
#If you exported the envvars in bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: If I open .bash_profile in nano, then add this will it work in CentOS? It is not working for me :-(. I doubt I can have two PATH for example? http://pastebin.com/z85KBMKm

Comment: Did you login after you had changed the file? It should be executed whenever a user login. Anyhow, did you source bash_profile in bashrc? It should solve this problem of "multiple" PATH. If it doesn't, let me know and I'll think of something else :)

Comment: Okay I solved it. I used nano and the code from pastebin. Problem was I had to disconnect from SSH, and then reconnect for changes to take affect. JAVA_HOME works fine, appears PATH does too.