# Writing files in hdfs in C++ (libhdfs)

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to write an interface in C++ to write files in hdfs using libhdfs.so. My target hadoop version is 2.0.2-alpha

The below code

```
 hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("127.0.0.1",8020);
 if (!fs)
 {
    printf("Hadoop file system returned null. \n");
    return 0;
 }
```

provides the following error while running:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Updated the CLASSPATH accordingly but still getting this error. 
Any idea what is the step I am missing here? All the .so files are linked correctly.

Comment: i would imagine this has nothing to do with the C++ code. why is java getting involved? wherever that is - that is where the problem is.

Comment: Check your Java installation, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11808829

Comment: @jheriko Hadoop is a java application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command to find the java classpath needed by hadoop

> $hadoop classpath

And add all of these paths to environment variable CLASSPATH

> $export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:`hadoop classpath`

[Here](https://github.com/QwertyManiac/cdh4-libhdfs-example) is a example of libhdfs for CDH4. Notice the environment settings in exec.sh