# Error: Could not find or load main class JDK

Tags: java, eclipse

im working with eclipse indigo, i created 2-3 work spaces and all are working fine, last day i was making a new work space same as i created before, but when i tried to start tomcat server or maven build to my project im getting the following error `"Error: Could not find or load main class JDK"` 
i went to `Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs`  and checked the setting of JDK and JRE but still having the same error with both JDK/JRE. also my old work spaces are working fine with same settings. i also checked the environmental variable for Java home and that is pointing to the same location where Java is installed.

Can any one help me to find out the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589718/compiler-error-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-sun-tools-javac-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to environmental variable and get the location of JDK_HOME, then run the command prompt and went to the JDK_HOME location,
There i run the following script

`unpack200 -r -v -l tools.pack tools.jar` and everything worked fine.
hope this will help someone. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java classpath may not set correctly.

On Linux OS,

Method 1: Set the right environment variable `CLASSPATH`.

```
echo "export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:." >> /etc/profile
```

Method 2: Add `" -classpath . "` to the java command

For example,

```
java -classpath . Test.class
```