# Main Class Not Found when Compiling Hadoop Sample Program

Tags: java, hadoop, digital-ocean, word-count

Hi i'm new to Hadoop and just started learning a couple days ago. I just followed the instructions from Digital Ocean to [setup a Hadoop cluster](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10). Afterwards I just tried a simple example program called WordCount from the [Hadoop docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html).

My hadoop version is 2.5.1 which is the same version with what is used on the tutorial, and it's running on Ubuntu Precise. I'm ensuring that I've done the proper setup as the tutorial said. Here's the end of my **~/.bashrc** contents.

```
        ...
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

Also, I checked on my java home config and the result is like below

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1         manual mode
```

So i changed all JAVA_HOME value both in bashrc and hadoop-env.sh files to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` . I'm ensuring as well that the Dfs and Yarn are both started.

However, when i **compile** the WordCount.java using this command

```
hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
```

Nothing is going my way. I got this error. Note that i'm using Hadoop command instead bin/hadoop as the command is working properly since it was defined in `bashrc` file.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

What is the possible cause of this error and how to get rid of this? It might be java classpath issue i think, but i'm still not be able to figure out the detail. Every workarounds regarding this problem i got are about executing `java` or `javac` command, not `hadoop` command.

I just want to get the sample program working first, before getting started to learn how it works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Perhaps a `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` will do the trick. Can you run `javac -version` at all ?

Comment: @blackSmith `java -version` was resulting javac 1.6.0_33

Comment: I was asking bout `javac` not `java`. The problem arose most probably due the unavailability of `javac` in the classpath. Try `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64` and then add `JAVA_HOME` to `Path` as shown earlier. It should should work.

Comment: Hi i just tried your suggestion, i changed JAVA_HOME to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64` and did `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`. But it shew `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main`

Answer (score 3):

The [Apache Hadoop tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) assumes that the environmental variables are set as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

Perhaps the [Digital Ocean hadoop tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10), which I also followed, ought to recommend adding those two latter variables to the ~/.bashrc so that it ends up looking like this:

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

It worked for my installation.  See the new compiled class files listed in the output:

Before:

```
ubuntu@mail:/usr/local/hadoop$ ls
bin  include  lib      LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  README.txt  share              WordCount.java
etc  input    libexec  logs         output      sbin        WordCount_classes
```

After:

```
ubuntu@mail:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
ubuntu@mail:/usr/local/hadoop$ ls
bin      input    LICENSE.txt  output      share              WordCount$IntSumReducer.class
etc      lib      logs         README.txt  WordCount.class    WordCount.java
include  libexec  NOTICE.txt   sbin        WordCount_classes  WordCount$TokenizerMapper.class
```

Another helpful resource was this:

> http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-634996.html Append the
>   following lines to the opened .bashrc file, save it and close: export
>   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22" export
>   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin issue the following command in the terminal:
>   source $HOME/.bashrc
>
> please refer this blog post for more info
>   (http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2011/01/easiest-way-to-install-java-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try executing from hadoop directory

> cd YARN_HOME
>   bin/hadoop jar **`absolute path to jar file`** WordCount **`input path`** `output path in hdfs`

Check out the below link
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0

Comment: which jar file are you meaning?

Comment: It is location of the jar file which contains the WordCount program and its dependencies.

Comment: hi, even the code is not compiled yet and hence i executed hadoop WordCount.java but it's failed.

Comment: Hi Rijalul, Please convert your java file to executable jar and add the manifest file for main class. Then simply run >"hadoop jar WordCount.jar input_path output_path"

Answer (score 2):

I Think Java is not enabled correctly. So please go to the hadoop-env.sh file and enable the java. Also check the java version and jre version. Both must be of the same version.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop requires jdk path for JAVA_HOME. Make sure that you have set jdk path and not jre. It seems you have installed java manually. Check version for javac to ensure it is enabled.

```
javac -version
```

Check [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23963506/3496666).

Answer (score 1):

`Assuming you are using Eclipse or any other IDE`,
As i mentioned in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063886/map-reduce-client-jars-for-2-4-1-hadoop-in-eclipse/27086746#27086746) post, create a `maven` based simple wordcount project with your class.
So all dependencies will be handled. Next `Right click` on your project and select `Export` option and give a name `<hadoop-example>.jar` and then next, next generate a jar file for your wordcount project.

> You don't need to explicitly compile your programs, 
>   Eclipse will do it for you once export is successful

If you installed hadoop on the same machine, then `start all the daemons` and check using `jps` whether all daemons started or not.
Else copy the jar file to Virtual Machine where hadoop is installed.
 Go to the jar location and run the following command.

```
hadoop jar <hadoop-example>.jar <fully qualified main class name> hdfsInputPath hdfsOutputPath
```

This will run your main class (`WordCount` in your case)
One should use the above command to run any hadoop program using command line by using jar file and then main class name(`WorkCount`) in your case.
You can make the `WordCount` as application entry point Main class while exporting the jar file. So you don't need to give the fully qualifed name. it would be like this.

```
hadoop jar <hadoop-example>.jar  hdfsInputPath hdfsOutputPath
```

Please try this and let us know if it helps you.
**Update:** As mentioned in the comments, IDE is not using.

> The above paths you set up is used by `Map/Reduce` while running the
>   program.

But before you run you should make a jar which needs all the dependents to compile.
So take one variable as `HADOOP_CLASSPATH_LIBS` and assign all the jars in the
 `<installed-hadoop>/share/hadoop/<subfolder>/lib`.
`For every jar, you should give the absolute path and export this variable`.
Which will enable you to compile and then make a jar file. Once you are having jar, you can follow the above steps to run it.
If need more help, can assist.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse. This is running on Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:<path to hadoop libs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop work with both openjdk and oracle jdk, but you are using oracle jdk.
I had same problem so I did following things.

```
1)export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
2)export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
3)export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

After running this command in terminal you will be able to compile java file.
Hadoop is not able to find correct java path, that is why you are getting that error.