# Map Reduce client jars for 2.4.1 hadoop in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

When I run my `hadoop mapreduce word count jar` in `hadoop` folder in shell, it is running properly and the output is generated correctly,

Since I use `yarn` in case of `hadoop 2.4.1`, when I run from eclipse for `MapReduce Sample program`, MAP process completed and getting failed in reduce process.

Its clear that the problem is with jar configuration.

**Please find the jars, I have added...**

[image]

**This is the error I got**

> INFO: reduce task executor complete. Nov 21, 2014 8:50:35 PM
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job run WARNING:
>   job_local1638918104_0001 java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.setLocalMapFiles(Ljava/util/Map;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.setLocalMapFiles(Ljava/util/Map;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:309)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:562)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     ... 1 more

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot, you are manually adding all the dependent jars to the classpath.
**It's highly recommended to use maven** for this, which will automate the process of adding dependent jars to the classpath. We just need to add main dependent jars.
I used the following dependencies in pom.xml which helped me to run without any issues..

```
<properties>
    <hadoop.version>2.5.2</hadoop.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**come to your problem,**
I checked in the classpath, there are exactly **82 jar** files available.
It will be tedious job to find each jar like this.
You can add the functional wise jars [**HERE**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop).
Other workaround would be, add all the jar files in installed hadoop directory path as `<hadoop-installed>/share/hadoop/` and add all jars from all the lib folder. which is the best thing you can do.. or
**Add only avro specific jars, because exception thrown by avro class as per the screenshot.** This could solve avro jars issue. but you may face other dependecy issues.
 I also faced the same problem while working with Hadoop V1. So later i realized and using Maven with Hadoop V2. So no worries of dependent jars.
 Your focus will be on Hadoop and Business needs. :)
Hope it helps you..