# What are the correct jar files to import to Eclipse to write MapReduce programs with the new APIs?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to re-write a `MapReduce` program to use stop using deprecated `APIs` such as e.g. `DistributedCache` (and use `job.addCacheFile` instead). I've imported `hadoop-core-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.2.0.jar` but it doesn't seem to be working. Help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063886/map-reduce-client-jars-for-2-4-1-hadoop-in-eclipse/27086746#27086746) will help you to run Hadoop V2 in Eclipse with maven based project or other work around is mentioned as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the jar by looking for the required classes: http://www.findjar.com/index.x

Comment: That didn't even return a result for org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce even.

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354309/handling-error-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-taskattemptcontext

Comment: I've now tried with hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.2.jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.5.2 and it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Maven dependency that you need to include:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you are using many other dependent jars that use Hadoop jars as dependency then make sure all of them are compiled against the right versions of Hadoop.