# File location of tools.jar?

Tags: java, hadoop, java-8, tools.jar

I'm trying to configure a single node Hadoop environment on my iMac 10.9.5. This has been a much larger pain than I anticipated and I have Java to thank for a lot of that. I've spent the past two hours dealing with this issue.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

I've looked at the JDK8 docs and a ton of forums searching for the reason and have narrowed it down to two.

1. When I installed JDK8, something went wrong and it wasn't included in the install.
2. For whatever reason, tools.jar isn't in reaching distance of JAVA_HOME. This will require to find out the path for tools.jar in Java8 and link to JAVA_HOME, which I haven't been able to find.

I would really like a better understand of what is going wrong and why. Also, the path to tools.jar would be really useful!

Thanks!

Comment: You should be aware that tools.jar is _going away_ in Java 9.  So if you've got code that depends on knowing its location, that code is going to have to change.

Comment: The longevity of this code isn't too important to me. It's for a class so once I turn it in, I probably won't come back to it except for syntax reminders. That's really good to know though. It will be interesting to see how Hadoop changes with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the deal, I'm an idiot. Through my freaking out (I'm stressed because I'm on a pretty tight deadline), I had over looked some pretty fundamental information. One was the JAVA_HOME environment variable. For me, this was `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home`, which I added to my .bash_profile. While I had this set correctly before I wrote this question, I hadn't made the connection when looking over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589718/compiler-error-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-sun-tools-javac-m). Artur clearly states that tools.jar is in your **JAVA_HOME/lib directory**. After reading this forum, which explicitly states that tools.jar was at the path below.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/
```

Or if you're looking for tools.jar for Java 8, then it will be in...

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/
```

Ok, so I've found tools.jar, but now I need to know where to put because Java isn't seeing it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675765/adding-to-the-classpath-on-osx) also explicitly states that tools.jar needs to be in **~/Library/Java/Extensions**. What do you know, I copy it over, Bob's your uncle, and everything works as it should. Only wish I had a post like this to guide me at noon today instead 9:45pm.

Hopefully this saves someone else in the future!