# Jboss 7 fails to start in WIndows 7

Tags: java, windows, jboss7.x

I am trying to install  `Jboss 7` on `Windows 7` . Software version details are as follows:

Java: jdk1.8.0_20

Jboss: jboss-as-7.1.0

Following environmental variables are set

```
CLASSPATH:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin
JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```

But while trying to start `JBOSS` , it is failing with the following error.

`java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object`

Any clues how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Your OS Win7 is 32bit or 64 bit?
and I hope you downloaded the respective 32bit or 64 bit Java JDK.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object)

Comment: Verified Windows and Java JDK are of 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the classpath should point to jars, not to scripts.
read about the classpath and path [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html) and [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/10/how-to-set-path-for-java-unix-linux-and.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the launch configuration, check that the right JRE System Library is on the Classpath