# In Ubuntu java -version gives Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

I have Ubuntu 64 bit 13.10 I have manually install java 8 in my machine
But When i do

```
java -version
```

it gives me

```
orbit@parth-desktop:~$ java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Need help on this. I have installed java in /usr/lib/jvm folder

Comment: What are the Xmx/Xms arguments ? Check the _JAVA_OPTIONS system variable , if its not there use `export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xms64m -Xmx128m -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JRE 1.7 returns: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object)

Comment: I have tried your solution but giving same error for java -version

Comment: java -fullversion is working fine for me but java -version not working

Answer (score 1):

According to Rigg802 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object), you most likely installed the jvm without proper permissions. If you look at that link, he reccomends uninstalling and reinstalling with proper permissions (ie sudo), and if that doesn't work he has some more  solutions as well.

Comment: I have checked that site , but that solution is not working. Previously i Have java7 which was working fine.. i have unistall it and then tried to manual install java 8 but facing same issue on fresh machine also.