# Cassandra windows, won't start up

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Installed it, Datastax CE, at first came up, but OpsCenter said agent was not up, although it seemed to be running.

So I reboot, hoping it might be happier. Opposite. Now Cassandra Service and Agent won't even start.

Going into logs I see

> 2015-07-28 16:12:47 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Any idea what else I have to do? I have JDK 1.8, Eclipse etc. Nothing else complains.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this locally? What OS? What method did you use to install?

Comment: Windows. like it said in the title. Windows 7 to be more specific. The installer. datastax-community-64bit_2.1.8.msi

Comment: Cassandra 2.2 I'm assuming?

Comment: Don't know. Whatever comes with DataStax CE 2.1.8

Comment: Okay, no that would be 2.1.8. I guess you're in a tricky spot because 2.2 is not stable, but windows support in 2.1.x is still pretty iffy. Anyway, you should at least be able to start cassandra without getting the error above. I'm not near a windows box but check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object

Comment: Installed latest jdk-8u51-windows-x64 via installer. Made no difference. Bah. Nothing else has a problem with my Java. I'm a developer, 18 years Java. Would be nice if the DataStax s/w just worked. Anyway, thanks for trying

Comment: And java --version comes back?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Looks like a classpath issue your JVM installation messed up - https://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/

Answer (score 1):

If cassandra won't start do the following:

1) try renaming the following path
C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog

2) if it doesn't work start cassandra as follows:
C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin>cassandra.bat

the console should tell you where the error is.

Good luck!

Comment: Renaming `commitlog` to `commitlog.old` worked for me, thanks!