# Calling RKEA library causes fatal error in Rstudio and R

Tags: java, r, session, abort

When I install the package RKEA in R, it seems to be all good. However, when I call the library, it causes a fatal error and the session is aborted immediately.

Once, I also saw this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM (java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object)
```

I added the path which has jvm.dll to the environmental variables as shown in this stackoverflow page:
[JRE 1.7 returns: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object)

Also, I'm using Java 8

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Please add your OS, version of R and RKEA

Comment: OS - Windows 8.1, R version 3.1.2, RKEA 0.0-6 @Pascal