# Java: NoClassDefFoundError and looked & tried the solutions of the similar questions

Tags: java

I have been using the following command from this [website](https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph) :

```
java -Xbootclasspath:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/rt.jar;jar/batik-all.jar;jar/xml-apis-ext.jar -javaagent:target/javacg-0.1-SNAPSHOT-dycg-gent.jar="incl=org.apache.batik.*,org.w3c.*;" -jar dacapo-9.12-bach.jar batik
```

and I am getting the following error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError:java/lang/Object
```

I have tried the following:

1)my java-version is perfectly working and I can run other programs as well.

2)there is no java.exe file in C:/Windows/System32

3)I reinstalled java

4)I have rt.jar in the specified folder and the rt.jar file is unpacked

Any help would be great!

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JRE 1.7 returns: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object)

Comment: Nope, I tried the answers said there. Please read my description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because of spaces in the path to `rt.jar` file.

Try surrounding it with doublequotes as below:

```
java -Xbootclasspath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/rt.jar";jar/batik-all.jar;jar/xml-apis-ext.jar -javaagent:target/javacg-0.1-SNAPSHOT-dycg-gent.jar="incl=org.apache.batik.*,org.w3c.*;" -jar dacapo-9.12-bach.jar batik
```