# i changed jre and now all programs have error

Tags: java, eclipse, path, syntax-error

i changed jre in eclipse and now all of my programs have an error 
i dont know what jre was using?all programs have this error:`Error occurred during initialization of VM`
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

sorry for off screen :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWfVL.jpg)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to JDK instead of JRE. 
This might solve your problem

Comment: Below link my help you. 
 http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm
Read Libraries tab-->Add Library
At this point you have to set your C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1....