# Unable to run ant command---Java,Ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm getting an error as
"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object"

Anyway to resolve this?

Comment: That’s pretty bizarre.  I would download the JDK directly from oracle.com and install it anew.

Comment: If VGR's suggestion doesn't resolve it, possibly check out the suggestions on these posts: [Error while starting eclipse “Error occurred during initialization of VM”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169756/error-while-starting-eclipse-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm) and [JRE 1.7 returns: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object)