# Java Error occured Windows 10

Tags: java, installation

i've got an error in java because i had to reinstall windows.

> Error occured during initialization of VM

I tried in CMD to use java and the exact same error occurs!
I reinstalled java jre and removed jdk, still nothing helped. Any idea on how to solve this?

To make sure that it was not working i searched for Bukkit and tried to run the server, the exact same thing happens.
When i tried java -version
[image]

Comment: type `java -version` in the command line to check if you have it installed.

Comment: @DimaSan The same thing happens!I'll edit the post to upload a pic of it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JRE 1.7 returns: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, the problem was with the `PATH`.

Go to your environmental variables and  check if there is a variable pointing to `java.exe` in `jre` directory. Reinstalling `jre` should solve the problem but to avoid it you can try the following:

The variable pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk<version>` should be called `JAVA_HOME` and the path variable should be extended with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\` and `%JAVA_HOME%` itself. Then somehow it might have the advantage to `javapath`

Comment: The exact same error happens.

Comment: can you go to java/bin folder on your cmd and run `java -version` there?

Comment: it worked perfectly!  Now what am i supposed to do to make it work whithout being in the java folder?