# Java.exe: Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, java-home

Each time I try to launch `java.exe`, in this case `java.exe -version`, I get this output:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

I searched on Google for a solution but nothing works...

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Java?

Comment: "Nothing works" is not a problem statement we can help with. Sorry. What version of java have you installed, how did you install, ... a ton of things that might matter here.

Comment: It could be result of improper Java installation. This link address some of the causes might come handy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object

Comment: Thank you all! I've solved it by setting the JAVA_HOME to the JRE, not the JDK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to fully qualified path of the directory that contains  bin/java.exe

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much! The problem was that my JAVA_HOME  was set to the JDK, not the JRE :)

Answer (score 1):

Just Delete java.exe in c:/programdata/oracle/java/javapath_target_xxxxxx/

Comment: I’m sorry, but this answer has already been answered a year ago. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: That's a good answer. solve my problem.  
when i reinstall the jdk1.8.0_172, The same error was arisen.  
my JAVA_HOME is correct, then find and delete java.exe in javapath_target_xxxxx.   
the error is disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your installed java bin directory contains rt.jar