# React Native Error - yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, compiler-errors

I am not able to run the sample react Native AwesomeProject project.

Can anyone help? Below is the details.

> C:\Users\dip\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
>   'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Scanning 557 folders for symlinks in C:\Users\dip\AwesomeProject\node_mo
>   ules (31ms)
>   JS server already running.
>   Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat instal
>   Debug)...
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Comment: Note: If you don't have administrator privileges on your system, `npm install -g yarn` will not add yarn to your executable path, which will produce this error.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yarn is a tool created by facebook as an efficient alternative for npm. In your case.. it is just informing that Yarn is not installed in your system. It is not the culprit.

The problem lies in `Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object Could not install the app on the device` line. It looks like an error with the Java installation.

Solution: Go to `C:\Windows\System32` directory and delete `java.exe` (or rename it to something like `java.exe.old`)

refer this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577609/5597641.

btw you can install Yarn by typing `npm install -g yarn` in your command prompt.

Comment: for `Node.js >=16.10` we should use `corepack enable` as mentioned in [yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)

Answer (score 255):

I faced the same issue and it got resolved by below command

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Comment: this resolved my issue after installing yarn via choco (failed to run on yarn install)

Comment: After running this command it was not working for me, then I go to C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm and deleted yarn.ps1 then it works!

Comment: After installing yarn, You can check whether the path is set or not. If its not set, copy the location of users/../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/yarn/bin and paste it under path in environment variables.

Answer (score 30):

you have to install yarn globally in your windows OS type this in CMD

```
npm install -g yarn
```

you can check yarn version by typing `yarn --version` on CMD

Answer (score 22):

Step 1: Run the below command

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Step 2: Check that Yarn is installed by running:

```
yarn --version
```

Step 3: If the above version command is not running then go to your `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm`and delete `yarn.ps1` if it is there.

Done!!!

Answer (score 17):

You should probably insert your Yarn folder in your Environment Variables.

If you already performed the command

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and still can't use yarn via terminal, check the following folder: `C:\Users\[your user]\AppData\Roaming\npm`

If there`s a yarn file there, just put that directory in your Path variable.

Answer (score 11):

Computer > Properties > Advanced System Setting > Environment Variables > Path edit add ; code

C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;
OR
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\;

Comment: for Windows after changing system environments you need to close and reopen the terminal

Comment: In my case, Yarn was installed in `C:\Users\LAV\Username\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin` and I added this to Path. I also had to close VSCode for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 9):

Go here https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

Install

Restart any terminals you had open.

> yarn -v

...for confirmation

You should be good to go

Answer (score 8):

install node [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and then run `npm install -g yarn` command in terminal

Answer (score 5):

If you are facing this error yarn: The term 'yarn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. then Just run this command

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and Check yarn version in your systems

```
yarn -v
```

After this installation, you are showing  above error then go to this page

```
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable
```

yarn install by manual

Answer (score 5):

I faced same I did:

```
1.npm install -g yarn 

Then I faced this error *"yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is  disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at.."*

        2.Go to C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm and delete yarn.ps1

        3. Then run -> yarn install
```

Answer (score 4):

if you typed `npm install -g yarn` and getting still the same error then update your node and npm to latest stable version, whenever you install node to latest version npm also updated so one way to solve this problem is installing node from its official website

Answer (score 3):

Try npx yarn start. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I install yarn as following :

1. in powershell env:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

this command will give you a correct execution policy

2. npm install -g yarn
3. yarn --version

Quoted from https://www.nextofwindows.com/fix-unable-to-run-yarn-in-windows-terminal-powershell

Answer (score 2):

you need to set your environment variable
-go to your yarn folder then bin
-copy that path
-save it in your environment variable as yarn

Answer (score 1):

I use this option to install https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable

[image]

then download and install. After close, the terminal then opens again and now is working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, in particular, yarn cannot be installed globally on my pc, but I have it installed on it. On MAC, I don't have this problem. I ran it locally to solve my specific problem, I don't recommend using it, but to get out of it quickly, you can run it NPX first "attention, you must have it installed before."

```
example: npx yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the path that `npm config get prefix` returned to my users `PATH` environmental variable.