# React Native Error - yarn' is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run a `reactnative` application. I have updated the `npm` along with its package dependencies.
With the following series of command

```
npm install
```

Followed by

```
npm update
```

Then

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Then i tried to run yarn as `yarn start`

Even after all the updates it says yarn is not recognized. But when install a fresh reacnative app as per its documentation and run yarn it works, but not working  with this reactnative project.

I am using react native `"0.55.3"`

I looked over SO and found this thread which has same issue as me. but those answers does not work for me .
[React Native Error - yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313178/react-native-error-yarn-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

if anyone can help i will really appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: what is the output of yarn --version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the error is related to yarn itself? What's your exact error?

You might try installing yarn [from their website](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) and restarting your computer just to ensure your commandline knows where it is.

Comment: apparently seems that install with npm didn't work. When i install the msi from the link you gave it worked :)
Thank you so much. I thought it was an issue reactnative

Answer (score 1):

Check path at environment variables, If it's not there add it manually.

The installation prompt shows that where it was installed.

In my case Its,

path : C:\Users<User name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn\bin

Adding the Path manually solved my issue.
(Reopen the command prompt after setting the path)

Or

The problem may be the one extra "\" was missing after the bin in your path.

Go to Environment Variables and change the path as follows

With error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin (Not working)

solved : C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\ (Working)

Answer (score 0):

On linux restarting the terminal helped me.