# An Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java

The exact error I'm getting is

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I get this error when I type in java -version or do anything relating to java. I've tried reinstalling with no luck, may JAVA_HOME is set to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231
```

And my path variable is set to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
and also
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have a look on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-java-version-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-obje.

And remove this C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath if it is set.

Comment: This didn't resolve my issue, that's why I've created this

Answer (score 0):

open command promt 
step 1: type java .It will display a big list.If it does not show any thing then uninstall your java and reinstiall lower version.
step 2: type javac .It should display a big list then you jdk is working properly .
If it shows command not found output then your have not assigned enviroment variables correcly.
Follow this link to set path:[enter link description here](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java)

Comment: Hey! I've tried reinstalling a previous version and it yielded the same result. When I type in javac a long list pops up so I assume it's working. Unfortunately this didn't fix it but thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you tried typing java also,if it the list doest popups then set envirolment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled both my jdk, jre, and java in general.