# ant build: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, ant

I am facing an issue with java build using ant.

I have installed jdk 1.5, ant 1.7.1, and configured env paths.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_06

$ echo $ANT_HOME
/home/.../..../apache-ant-1.7.1/bin
```

When I run 'ant' at root of an ant project, I get error:

```
$ ant
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

What am I missing in my configuration?

Edit:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-8u372-ga~us1-0ubuntu1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b09, mixed mode)
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_06/bin/java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JRE 1.7 - java version - returns: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-java-version-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-obje)

Comment: 1) What does `java -version` say?  2) What does `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_06/bin/java -version` say?  3) What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: @StephenC, updated my post.

Comment: Basically you have a broken installation of Java 1.5.

Comment: I should also note that the last public release of JDK 1.5 (aka Java 5.0) was in 2009.  And the `1.5.0_06` build was released in December 2005.  It is nearly 18 years out of date.